# Dividing different shaped numpy multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've tried the second example below and it didn't work, but a small scale-example for dividing a numpy array with another one works fine. What's the difference? How can I get the actual division to work?

A small scale example of what I am trying to do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> b = np.asarray([2, 2, 2])
>>> a / b           # works as expected
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 3]])
```

The actual division that I am trying to get working

```
>>> a = np.random.random((9, 31, 2, 5))
>>> b = np.random.random((9, 31, 2))
>>> a / b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,31,2,5) (9,31,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
a = np.random.random((9, 31, 2, 5))
b = np.random.random((9, 31, 2, 1))
print((a/b).shape)
```

yields

```
(9, 31, 2, 5)
```

Comment: Think you are missing the third dimension for b... Try recopying the code in the answer

Comment: Any idea of how to convert the shape from `(9, 31, 2)` to `(9, 31, 2, 1)`?

Comment: Sure `b = b.reshape(9, 31, 2, 1)` or `b = np.expand_dims(b, -1)`